# определить в каких блоках находятся файлы linux

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Есть три файла размерами 1 байт, 1 мегабайт и 20 мегабайт. Нужно объяснить, в каких блоках они находятся?
т.е. указать конкретные блоки, где находятся эти файлы.
я использовал команду stat, но она показывает просто кол-во блоков, занимаемых файлом.
файловая система ext2/ext3

Comment: Какой смысл вы вкладываете в вопрос «каких»? Какая конкретно информация о блоках вас интересует?

Comment: Неплохо бы уточнить о какой фс идёт речь. А то fat12 и btrfs очень разные

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я так понимаю, что нужно указать конкретные блоки, где размещены эти файлы. это возможно? я использовал stat, там показывает только кол-во блоков, которые занимает этот файл

Comment: Есть программка [fragview](https://github.com/i-rinat/fragview), которая визуализирует блоки, занимаемые файлами. У неё в описании написано, что используются «FIEMAP and FIBMAP ioctls» — возможно, вам стоит покопаться в этом направлении

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не самый правильный совет. Посмотрите документацию по ext2. А дальше команда dd может прочитать сырые данные из раздела. Находим суперблок, и далее по документации можно найти в каких блоках находятся файлы.